# Can't connect to standalone React Native Debugger

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-debugger

I've been having trouble getting the standalone React Native Debugger to work.  I'm running an expo project and testing on android device.  When I select Debug Remote JS, it opens up http://localhost:19000/debugger-ui/ in my web browser each time.  My standalone debugger on port 19000 just says Waiting for React to connect. Not seeing any errors anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure the device is connected via adb

```
adb devices
```

[image]

2. if you see your device, please run this command

```
adb reverse tcp:8097 tcp:8097
```

3. and restart your debugger

Comment: I don't see the device under adb devices.  I'm currently running Ubuntu in WSL and connected to the device via expo and wifi